# ModelNotFoundException - No query results for model [App\User]

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

From the form in my edit view, I'm calling the update function:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $id  = Auth::user();
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('user');
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

*ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125: No query results for model [App\User].*

I'm not passing the $id because i'm updating the Auth Id.

Not sure what's wrong and how to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is just enough in case you want to update logged in User.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    Auth::user()->update($request->all());
    return redirect('user');
}
```

Comment: Super, that's even better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@pinkalvansia has a great answer and solution for you.

However, I also wanted to note that I believe you would need to use:

`Auth::user()->id` to get the currently logged in user's ID. Your code would like this:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user_id  = Auth::user()->id;

    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);

    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('user');
}
```

Hope this is helpful!